# Read and write into shared thread variables

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

first of all i am new to threads and shared variables. So please be kind with me ;-)

I'm having a class called `Routing`. This class recieves and handles messages. If a message is of type `A` the `Routing`-Object should pass it to the `ASender` Object which implements the `Runnable` Interface. If the message is of type `B` the `Routing`-Class should pass it to the `BSender` Object.

But the `ASender` and `BSender` Objects have common variables, that should be stored into the `Routing`-Object.

My idea now is to declare the variables as synchronized/volatile in the `Routing`-Object and the getter/setter also.

Is this the right way to synchronize the code? Or is something missing?

Edit: Added the basic code idea.

RoutingClass

```
public class Routing {

private synchronized Hashtable<Long, HashSet<String>> reverseLookup;
private ASender asender;
private BSender bsender;

public Routing() {
    //Constructor work to be done here.. 
    reverseLookup = new Hashtable<Long, HashSet<String>>();

}

public void notify(TopicEvent event) {

    if (event.getMessage() instanceof AMessage) {
        asender = new ASender(this, event.getMessage())

    } else if (event.getMessage() instanceof BMessage) {
        bsender = new BSender(this, event.getMessage())

    }
}

public synchronized void setReverseLookup(long l, Hashset<String> set) {
    reverseLookup.put(l, set);

}

public synchronized Hashtable<Long, Hashset<String>> getReverseLookup() {
    return reverseLookup;
}
}
```

ASender Class

```
public class ASender implements Runnable {

private Routing routing;
private RoutingMessage routingMessage;

public ASender(Routing r, RoutingMessage rm) {
    routing = r;
    routingMessage = rm;
    this.run();
}

public void run() {
    handleMessage();
}

private void handleMessage() {
    // do some stuff and extract data from the routing message object

    routing.setReverseLookup(somethingToSet)
}
}
```

Comment: We can't tell if the code is right without seeing the code. Code matters.

Comment: [Do I look like a Guru?](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Guru_Myth)

Comment: Ok, i understand.. I'll add the code...

Comment: I think you are good to go. Just avoid nested synchronization, and if you have to, always lock in the same order. Google how to avoid java deadlocks, e.g. Listing 1 [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2001/jw-1012-deadlock.html) shows how NOT to do it.

Comment: So my basic code is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments:

1. Hashtable is a thread-safe implementation, you do not need another "synchronized" keyword see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400292/is-java-util-hashtable-thread-safe) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) for more information
2. Avoid coupling, try to work with interfaces or pass the hashtable to your senders, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) for more information
3. Depending on the amount of senders, you might want to use a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), it greatly improves the performance, see [ConcurrentHashMap and Hashtable in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646404/concurrenthashmap-and-hashtable-in-java) and [Java theory and practice: Concurrent collections classes](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07233/index.html)

This would conclude something like...:

```
public interface IRoutingHandling {

    void writeMessage(Long key, HashSet<String> value);

}

public class Routing implements IRoutingHandling {

    private final Hashtable<Long, HashSet<String>> reverseLookup;

    private ASender asender;
    private BSender bsender;

    public Routing() {
        //Constructor work to be done here.. 
        reverseLookup = new Hashtable<Long, HashSet<String>>();
    }

    public void notify(TopicEvent event) {
        if (event.getMessage() instanceof AMessage) {
            asender = new ASender(this, event.getMessage())

        } else if (event.getMessage() instanceof BMessage) {
            bsender = new BSender(this, event.getMessage())

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void writeMessage(Long key, HashSet<String> value) {
        reverseLookup.put(key, value);
    }

}

public class ASender implements Runnable {

    private IRoutingHandling _routingHandling;

    public ASender(IRoutingHandling r, RoutingMessage rm) {
        _routingHandling = r;
        routingMessage = rm;
        this.run();
    }

    public void run() {
        handleMessage();
    }

    private void handleMessage() {
        // do some stuff and extract data from the routing message object

        _routingHandling.writeMessage(somethingToSetAsKey, somethingToSetAsValue)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'll try to convert (is this the right term? I'm german..)  your thoughts.

Comment: One last question. Let's say i have a Vector. Since the Vector class is not thread safe, i have to synchronize on the add() and get() methodes, right? What is the better way? Synchronize via synchronized(vector) { vector.get(value); } Or public synchronized Vector<String> getVector(String value){ return vector.get(value); } ?

Comment: Actually, each of the methods of java.util.Vector is synchronized. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html, so again, there's no need to add any synchronized keyword.

Comment: Ok thank you. I had in my mind that the Vector isn't synchronized.